# Saving data from multiple tabs in a tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I've been tasked with making a few changes to an existing program.

One of those changes is implementing a 'save' button. 
When clicked, it will iterate through each tab and save the contents to a database, but I can't figure out how to access the data properly.

The tabs being added are separate views, each with their own viewmodel - the main view containing the tabcontrol also has its own viewmodel.

How would I go about accessing the tabcontrol, iterating through each tab and saving the data in an orderly fashion?
(At this point I'm not sure if it's relevant to show any code, but please do request whatever you'd need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that every tab supports changes saving, create a view model, that will be on top of tab view models:

```
// this is the base class for tab view models
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public void SaveChanges() {}
}

// this is the view model for tab container
public class EditorViewModel
{
    private SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var document in OpenedDocuments)
        {
            document.SaveChanges();
        }        
    }

    public EditorViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveChanges);
    }

    // this is your tabs
    public ObservableCollection<DocumentViewModel> OpenedDocuments { get; private set; }

    public ICommand SaveChangesCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you have all data accessible in your viewmodel, there is no need to iterate through the tabs in the tabcontrol. 
That 'save' button should bind to a command that collects data from each tabs viewmodel.

Comment: But he is not saving it to one file(It seems), and he needs to save it all to each individual file, or create a new file holding the text(Or whatever he needs to save) from the tab that doesn't have a file name, or the file no longer exists. Get what I mean? :D